# Set the background color within a cell range in a row (not using conditional formatting)

Tags: excel, vba

The copy paste code is terrible coding style but I needed a fast solution. I would like to change the cell background color of a few cells in a row(not column). I've wrote a few lines of code (below the code I copied and pasted) but am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Ultimately I would like the get the loop working so then I can later on check the value of the cell on different ranges of numbers.

```
If Range("C5").Value = 0 Then Range("C5").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("D5").Value = 0 Then Range("D5").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("E5").Value = 0 Then Range("E5").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("F5").Value = 0 Then Range("F5").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed

If Range("C8").Value = 0 Then Range("C8").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("D8").Value = 0 Then Range("D8").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("E8").Value = 0 Then Range("E8").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
If Range("F8").Value = 0 Then Range("F8").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
```

*****CODE I WOULD LIKE TO USE*****

```
  'Set myRange = Range("C5:F17")
    'Dim cell As Range
    'For Each cell In myRange.Rows(1)
    'If cell.Value = 0 Then cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    'Next cell
    'If myRange.Rows(1).Value = 0 Then myRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not CF? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: *not sure what I'm doing wrong* - where is the code failing or not doing what you want? what is expected result vs actual result? Also CF is much simpler in this case.

Comment: the code is failing within my for loop. It just won't execute.

Comment: `'If myRange.Rows(1).Value = 0 Then myRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed` won't work for sure, but the loop looks fine.

Comment: That was my original approach but I left that line commented out and used the loop. Which I also thought looked fine.

Comment: What does "just won't execute" mean? Error message?

Comment: yes, I get a runtime error '13'  message. I believe its a type mismatch error.

Comment: Add .Cells to make it myrange.Rows(1).Cells

Comment: @CDP1802 thank you so much that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Add .Cells to make it myrange.Rows(1).Cells. Reason is without it cell is a range $C$5:$F$5 which you can see with  Debug.Print cell.Address.

Comment: @Chris - yes effectively if you're looping through the `Rows(1)`, `cell` will refer to the entire `Row(1)`, not each individual cell in it.

Answer (score 0):

needs to be -> myrange.Rows(1).Cells to access each individual cell.